# ¿Cómo cambiar el Hint de un EditText desde un archivo .java? (TextInputLayout)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Lo que busco es que mediante un RadioButton (Cuando sea seleccionado) cambie el hint de un EditText, para que pueda mostrarse en la parte superior del EditText (así como lo hace el de voltaje). 
El hint que se muestra es el que coloco como inicial en mi código xml, sino coloco ningún hint en mi código xml no muestra ningún hint en la parte superior, y si coloco el hint de potencia por defecto en mi EditText entonces cuando cambio a corriente los pone encima.

[image: Vista de la aplicacion]

El código del EditText es este:

```
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_SegundoValorC1_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Y mi codigo que cambia el hint es el siguiente

```
RG_SeleccionC1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId){

                case R.id.RB_PotenciaC1_id:

                    et_SegundoValorC1.setHint("Potencia");
                    SP_SegundoValorC1.setAdapter(AdapterSP_Potencia);

                    if (!et_voltajeC1.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !et_SegundoValorC1.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        tv_ResultadoC1.setText(CalcularResistencia(VoltajeC1, SegundoValorC1));
                    }

                    break;

                case R.id.RB_CorrienteC1_id:

                    et_SegundoValorC1.setHint("Corriente");
                    SP_SegundoValorC1.setAdapter(AdapterSP_Corriente);

                    if (!et_voltajeC1.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !et_SegundoValorC1.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        tv_ResultadoC1.setText(CalcularResistencia(VoltajeC1, SegundoValorC1));
                    }

                    break;
            }

        }});
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cambie el hint y se muestre en la parte superior como lo hace la del voltaje?

Comment: Puedes compartir el código del xml completo?

Comment: Para hacer que el hint pase a la parte de arriba, tienes que poner el hint en el `TextInputLayout` y no en el `EditText`. Ademas solo se pasa a la parte de arriba hasta que le ingreses contenido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si era lo que necesitaba @AlfredoLopez